# How to make function be able to accept raw poniters as iterators?

Tags: c++

I have two functions that split a string and add tokens into vector:

```
template < typename InputIterator, typename ContainerType >
void Slice(InputIterator begin,
           InputIterator end,
           typename InputIterator::value_type delimiter,
           ContainerType& container)
{
    using CharType = InputIterator::value_type;
    InputIterator right = begin;
    while (true) {
      begin = find_if_not(right, end, [ delimiter ](CharType c) { return c == delimiter; });
      if (begin == end) {
        break;
      } else {
        right = find_if(begin + 1, end, [ delimiter ](CharType c) { return c == delimiter; });
        container.push_back(std::basic_string< CharType >(begin, right));
      }
    }
}

template < typename InputIterator, typename ContainerType >
void Slice(InputIterator begin,
           InputIterator end,
           InputIterator delimitersBegin,
           InputIterator delimitersEnd,
           ContainerType& container)
{...}
```

It works well in calls like

```
std::string headers;
std::vector<std::string> rawHeaders;
Slice(headers.begin(), headers.end(), '\0', rawHeaders)
```

and doesn't work for `const char*`:

```
auto begin = headers.c_str();
auto end = begin + headers.size();
Slice(begin, end, '\0', rawHeaders);
```

Errors are (I use MSVC2017 with MSVC2013 toolchain):

> error C2780: 'void Slice(InputIterator,InputIterator,InputIterator,InputIterator,ContainerType &)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void Slice(InputIterator,InputIterator,InputIterator::value_type,ContainerType &)
> With the following template arguments:
> 'InputIterator=const char *'
> 'ContainerType=std::vectorstd::string,std::allocator<_Ty>'

Update: added function body.
And currently it's preferred not to use additional features like std::span.
I was hoping for the following string constructor:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Update 2: Still doesn't work but for different reason, I tried to change delimiter type:

```
 template < typename InputIterator, typename ContainerType >
  void Slice(
      InputIterator begin,
      InputIterator end,
      typename std::iterator_traits< InputIterator >::value_type delimiter,
      //typename InputIterator::value_type delimiter,
      ContainerType& container)
  {
    using CharType = typename std::iterator_traits< InputIterator >::value_type;
```

Now it says:

> error C3861: 'find_if_not': identifier not found. see reference to function template instantiation 'void StringUtils::Slice<char*,std::vectorstd::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>(InputIterator,InputIterator,char,ContainerType &)' being compiled with [_Ty=std::string, InputIterator=char *,      ContainerType=std::vectorstd::string,std::allocator<std::string>

And also:

> error C3861: 'find_if': identifier not found

Comment: Raw pointers *are* iterators. The issue looks to be with that the functions expects a container to be passed at the end. You are passing in raw pointers and a `std::vector<std::string>` which clearly don't match.

Comment: @super `functions expects a container ... You are passing in raw pointers and a std::vector<std::string> which clearly don't match.` I don't get your point. Is vector not a container? Why doesn't it match?

Comment: @eerorika Ah, right. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SFINAE kicks in. The signature

```
template < typename InputIterator, typename ContainerType >
void Slice(InputIterator begin,
           InputIterator end,
           typename InputIterator::value_type delimiter,
           ContainerType& container)
```

is not a possible candidate because there is no nested member `::value_type` in a `const char*`.

You probably want this signature instead:

```
template < typename InputIterator, typename ContainerType >
void Slice(InputIterator begin,
           InputIterator end,
           typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type delimiter,
           ContainerType& container)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type delimiter,` because the type depends on `InputIterator`? Can't get it to work without.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Wrap it around your pointers. It's lightweight and fast.
I'm not sure if it's already in your toolchain.